# NSNotificationCenter Not Working Between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Ive been hitting the wall for two days on this hard (but simple for you) problem.

The problem is as follows:

1. I am posting a notification in the appdelegate
2. I am attempting to receive that notification in a viewcontroller but I cannot receive it.

Here is the code for this.

In the appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * someString;
@end
```

In the appdelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SomeContextExample.h"


@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.someString = @"Hello!";


    NSDictionary * userInfo = @{SomeContextExampleRef : self.someString};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomeContextExample"
                                                        object:nil
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];

return YES;
}
```

The "SomeContextExampleRef" is coming from a .h file as follows:

```
#ifndef SampleNotWorking_SomeContextExample_h
#define SampleNotWorking_SomeContextExample_h

#define SomeContextExampleRef @"SomeContextExampleRef"

#endif
```

Finally, in the viewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SomeContextExample.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"SomeContextExample"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:mainQueue
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
 {

     NSLog(@"got the notification!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! %@", note.userInfo);



 }];
}
```

My full code is attached here:
https://github.com/moomoo23/SampleNotWorking

Thank you for helping a beginner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try posting your notification when you are confident your "`ViewController`" object has instantiated and/or come into view. E.G. why not try it out by putting it into an "`IBAction`" method fired by some UIButton?

The observing view controller may or may not (more likely not in your case) be existing at the end of "`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`" in your app delegate.

Comment: You are faster than I am. In the midst of typing the same thing, deleted it. :D

Comment: ah i see.. here is my gap in understanding: if the viewcontroller is not existing at the end of didfinishlaunchingwithoptions, the posted message is NOT in memory? Meaning that, once the viewcontroller is existing, it cannot get this message at that point because the posted message becomes nil?

Comment: The posted notification you did up there gets discarded because there are no observers yet at the very end of launching your app.  You have to get that "`ViewController`" object into view (and instantiated) to get it's observer watching for those notifications.

Comment: ah darn!! Thank you so much! One last question (the Golden Question) how does one keep an observer on this notification persisted such that the viewcontroller when it does come into view can consume that notification?

Comment: I'd recommend having some object (***not*** a view controller) always in memory, like a singleton, doing the observing and setting some "`BOOL`" property that your view controller can query to see if it needs to do something once your view controller comes into view.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to post the notification after a delay using the  `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method.

Now, conceptually, why would you post a notification when the appFinsihedLaunching?.... just curious....  e

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. At a high level, I am pulling data from the server and I am storing it using coredata. But I need a way to inform my views that the fetch has completed .. hence the notification. Another possible explanation is that I have no idea what i am doing =)

Comment: @user330739. That makes sense.  But instead of posting the notification in the appDidFinishLoadingWithOptions method, I would launch the data fetch and the CoreData processing in a different thread in background, and that will give plenty of time for the view controllers to be instantiated and presented to be ready to get notifications.